# How do I create a file?

Tags: text-editor, tftp

I'm following instructions about [Installing and setting TFTPD in Ubuntu](http://www.davidsudjiman.info/2006/03/27/installing-and-setting-tftpd-in-ubuntu/). It asks to

> Create /etc/xinetd.d/tftp and put this entry:
>
> ```
> service tftp
> {
> protocol        = udp
> port            = 69
> socket_type     = dgram
> wait            = yes
> user            = nobody
> server          = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
> server_args     = /tftpboot
> disable         = no
> }
> ```

What does it mean to create? Is there any command I need to type? And *"put this entry"* - it means to type in one line all the lines above? I don't know Linux & I need your help please.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a (text) file with the given path (`/etc/xinetd.d/tftp`).

To do so:

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to open the *Run Application* dialog
2. Type `gksu gedit /etc/xinetd.d/tftp` and click on *Run*
3. Now type your password and the text editor `gedit` should start, with the new (empty) file already opened
4. Finally, copy and paste the lines from the guide to the new file and save it

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sudo nano /etc/xinetd.d/tftp
```

in terminal to edit that file. `nano` will automatically create that file, or open previous version of it already exists. You have to enter your password when sudo asks it, with something like

> [sudo] password for :

After `nano` opens, you can paste or write the contents of the file.

You can exit `nano` (very simple text editor) by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>. It'll then ask whether you want to save, press <kbd>Y</kbd> to save (or <kbd>N</kbd> to discard your changes).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a file at location /etc/xinetd.d/tftp and insert text into that file.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/xinetd.d/tftp
```

would open gedit. Enter text and save file.

Comment: gedit is for editing an existing file- how do i create new file?

Comment: Hi - i've tried it- & got an error message- "couldn't find the file /etc/xinetd.d/tftp please check that you typed the location correctly and try again"- what do i need to do?