# How do I disable overlay scrollbars?

Tags: overlay-scrollbars

It looks like Ubuntu 11.04 will come with [overlay scrollbars](http://design.canonical.com/2011/03/introducing-overlay-scrollbars-in-unity/) by default. I *do* like them, but I don't like the current mix of scrollbar types as many applications don't yet use those overlay scrollbars.

Is there a way to disable overlay scrollbars (**without** removing the `overlay-scrollbar` package)?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can disable the scrollbars either

- For your user:

  Add the line

  ```
    export LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0
  ```

  to the file `~/.xprofile` (create one, if it doesn't exist).
- Or globally:

  Create a file `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/99disable-overlay-scrollbars` and add above line (requires root permissions, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28291/how-do-i-create-a-file/28297#28297) about how to create a file as root).
- Or per application:

  - [Is there a way to blacklist an individual application from using overlay-scrollbars?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36448/is-there-a-way-to-blacklist-an-individual-application-from-using-overlay-scrollba)

Comment: Just one user: `echo export LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0 >> ~/.xprofile` *(note that the double '`>>`' is important, it means "append").*   To add for all users: `echo export LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0 | sudo tee -a /etc/X11/Xsession.d/99disable-overlay-scrollbars`

Comment: While this seems to have no effect for me (Ubuntu 12.04 with LXDE -- and yes, X was restarted after that change), [Erigami's variant](http://askubuntu.com/a/177160/68291) worked excellent. Just as a hint to try the other if one doesn't work :)

Comment: For 15.10 and 16.04 the variable is [named differently](https://askubuntu.com/a/710625/113421).

Comment: I remember that when I still used Unity desktop environment, I had to use this workaround to fix a scrollbar bug on Geany: `alias geany="LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0 geany"`

Answer (score 137):

In **12.04 LTS** there's a [slightly cleaner way to do it](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/03/disable-ubuntu-overlay-scrollbars-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/). Just run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface ubuntu-overlay-scrollbars false
```

in a terminal. Apps opened afterwards will have the non-ayatana scrollbar.

To get the default behavior back, run

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface ubuntu-overlay-scrollbars
```

If you are using **12.10 or later**, run

```
gsettings set com.canonical.desktop.interface scrollbar-mode normal
```

And to return to the default, run

```
gsettings reset com.canonical.desktop.interface scrollbar-mode
```

Comment: In 13.10 only the first one worked for me.

Comment: Thx! That was wonderful to get rid of that crap! :-)

Comment: Does not work on 14.04. htorque's answer does though.

Comment: Did not work for me with 12.04 and Xfce but htorque's answer worked.

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi: strange, it worked on my 14.04 perfectly. No idea where's your problem. Anyway, others on 14.04 shouldn't be afraid to try this way, it's less complicated than htorque's one.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in 15.10. `No such schema 'com.canonical.desktop.interface'`

Comment: In 16.04 LTS: 

No such key 'ubuntu-overlay-scrollbars'

Comment: For 15.10 and 16.04 see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/710625/113421) (although it's via env var, not `gsettings`).

Answer (score 30):

You can remove the scrollbars completely by typing

```
sudo apt-get remove overlay-scrollbar liboverlay-scrollbar
```

Comment: This is a merged in answer to deal with people who are happy with deleting the packages. It may well be a simpler fix.

Comment: Warning: Don't try this on 13.10!

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh - why? (at a guess it may try and remove  Unity etc, so loook at what the packages try to remove first).

Comment: 'liboverlay-scrollbar' does not exist in Ubuntu 15.10, so you cannot remove it

Answer (score 18):

Just disabling or removing the overlay-scrollbars as described by the other answers will get you back the scroll bars, but they will be missing the stepper buttons at the end of the bars because they have been disabled in the *Ambiance* theme. To re-enable them, put the following in the `~/.gtkrc-2.0` file:

```
style "default" {
  engine "murrine" {
    stepperstyle = 0
  }
}
```

and the following into the file `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`:

```
.scrollbar {
  -GtkScrollbar-has-backward-stepper: 1;
  -GtkScrollbar-has-forward-stepper: 1;
}
```

Usually, restarting the applications is enough for the changes to apply.

Comment: To make the stepper buttons better-looking, add this to .scrollbar: -GtkRange-slider-width: 16; -GtkRange-stepper-size: 17;

Comment: Thanks, this restores the steppers for me, but is there an easy way to fix the contrast on the scrollbars so they're not a totally unusable black on black?

Comment: That worked for me. I'm just surprised by the "murrine". Wondering whether that really applies to me. I thought I had metacity, or is metacity yet something else than the "engine"?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have done anything for me.  Is it because I'm running Cinnamon?  Or do I need to restart for it to take effect?

Comment: @PaulBrannan Uhh, that is a really old answer. I would be surprised if it was directly applicable, in particular to the Cinnamon desktop...

Answer (score 5):

Simply use utility `dconf-editor` or `gconf-editor`. If it is not already present you can install this from Ubuntu Software Center.

This utility is like Windows registry-editor where you can tweak system settings.
From entry `org > gnome > Desktop > Applications`.you find an item named *ubuntu-overlay-scrollbars*. Toggle the item off, logout/login and you're ready.

Comment: The path is org > gnome > desktop > interface in Ubuntu 14 but it doesn't work anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you're talking about ayatana scrollbar!

in the case that you want to have the old scrollbar style you only need to use the next command:

```
sudo apt-get remove overlay-scrollbar liboverlay-scrollbar liboverlay-scrollbar3
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In Ubuntu 12.04 you can just install [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com) and the option to disable the vertical overlay scrollbar is in **Tweaks -> Miscellaneous**. You'll need to log-off or reboot for the changes to take effect.

If you want the overlay scrollbar back at some point, you just go and enable it back again in the app. In addition you get a large number of tweaks at your disposition. I'd say this is the easiest way to achieve this.

Comment: This is what I did., using the instructions supplied in an answer to [another question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/258213/ubuntu-12-10-cannot-resize-any-window).

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
echo "export LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0" > /etc/X11/Xsession.d/80overlayscrollbars
```

You'll probably need to log off once.

More information / ideas can be found [here](http://ubuntu4beginners.blogspot.com/2011/04/disable-overlay-scrollbars-in-ubuntu.html).

Comment: pavlos G. beat me to it. The info is also confirmed [here](http://tips4linux.com/disable-the-overlay-scrollbars-in-ubuntu-1104/) and [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/how-to-disable-overlay-scrollbars-in.html)

Comment: Thanks for this, guys. As I absolutely despise the overlay scrollbars, I'll accept the answer that removes the packages, but I'm sure this info will be useful to others.

Comment: Careful with the single `>`, it will cause the file to be overwritten if it already exists (and thus destroy all previous changes). Better use `>>` instead to *append* the new setting.

Answer (score 3):

On 15.10 wily (libgtk-3-0) this worked for me:

```
export GTK_OVERLAY_SCROLLING=0
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work for me, though I inserted this into .xprofile as well. Does it really work for you? In which application you can see it take effect?

Comment: Where should this code be put?

Comment: This still works well for me on Xubuntu 18.04. To disable overlay scrollbars globally, put this line into a (new) file like `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/99disable-overlay-scrollbars`.

Answer (score 1):

When you try to uninstall `liboverlay-scrollbar` doesn't find it! To get rid of the transparent bars was easily fixed. I use leafpad.

Open a terminal :

1. `gksudo leafpad /etc/X11/Xsession.d/99disable-overlay-scrollbars`
2. Put your password in.
3. Type  `export LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0`
4. Save, Exit and reboot.

No more overlay slidebars or transparent slidebars.

Answer (score 0):

**Enabling classic/old style scrollbars**

For Ubuntu 14.x there are two ways:

Just use command:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.desktop.interface scrollbar-mode normal
```

Or install Unity Tweak Tool.

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Go to System > Scrollbars and set to Legacy.

**Changing colors and appearance**

After one of these two steps, you can further enhance the look of scrollbars if you are using default Ambiance theme. To do this, fire up (if you don't have sublime editor then replace it with whatever editor you are using like nano or gedit).

```
sudo subl /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css
```

Press Ctrl+F and type .scrollbar to find style section for scrollbars. Mine looks like below (annotated with /* MODIFIED ... / comments below):

```
.scrollbar,
.scrollbar.vertical {
    /* MODIFIED: next 3 lines */
    -GtkScrollbar-has-backward-stepper: 1;
    -GtkScrollbar-has-forward-stepper: 1;
    -GtkScrollbar-stepper_size = 14;
    -GtkRange-slider-width: 14;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-image: none;
}

.scrollbar.trough,
.scrollbar.trough.vertical {
    border-color: shade (@bg_color, 0.8);
}

.scrollbar.slider,
.scrollbar.slider:hover,
.scrollbar.button,
.scrollbar.slider.vertical,
.scrollbar.slider.vertical:hover,
.scrollbar.button.vertical {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: shade (@bg_color, 0.86);
    /* MODIFIED: next 1 line */
    background-image: -gtk-gradient (linear, left top, right top,
                                     from (shade (@dark_bg_color, 1.08)),
                                     color-stop (0.5, @dark_bg_color),
                                     to (shade (@dark_bg_color, 0.94)));
    box-shadow: inset 1px 0 shade (@bg_color, 1.1),
                inset -1px 0 shade (@bg_color, 1.01),
                inset 0 1px shade (@bg_color, 1.1),
                inset 0 -1px shade (@bg_color, 1.1);
}
```

Final result:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get rid of the overlay scrollbars using dconf-editor, by setting:

com.canonical.desktop.interface.scrollbar-mode='normal'

(Caveat, not sure about stepper buttons.)

Intuitively, if 'off' is normal, shouldn't it be the default? Someone deemed 'overlay-auto' the default. Just thankful to be rid of this horrifically unhelpful 'feature'. It cost me about two hours to find a solution. Hope to resolve the stepper-buttons issue based on the above information (thank you).

Comment: This is a combination of other answers already posted here.