# Is there a way to blacklist an individual application from using overlay-scrollbars?

Tags: 11.04, blacklist, overlay-scrollbars, code-blocks

I am having problems with some programs when using overlay-scrollbars, mainly Code::Blocks and Eclipse.

I've found several ways of disabling the overlay scrollbars completely, for all applications, but I like them and I don't want to do this.

Is there a way to blacklist only this applications from using the new scrollbars?

Answer (score 31):

I am going to answer my own question. Thanks to the user "SevenMachines" in ubuntuforums, I've found a way to disable overlay scrollbars for a specific application.
I did a shell script with the following (for eclipse, for example):

```
#!/bin/sh
LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0 eclipse
```

Then, make it executable, and using the "Menu editor", changed eclipse to point to the script.

Comment: I can confirm this works and is awesome!

Comment: Worked beautifully for me too. Kind of annoying that you have to do it though...

Comment: This is a fantastic solution, thank you! It allowed me to troubleshoot some of the problems I had with overlay scrollbars and Inkscape.

Answer (score 18):

Alternatively, in your `.bashrc` add the following

```
alias eclipse="LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0 eclipse"
```

In fact, you may also want to add `UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0` so unity menus work properly with eclipse, so that becomes:

```
alias eclipse="UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0 eclipse"
```

[**Note:** that this will only take effect once you restart your bash shell]

Comment: Take note that do `source .bashrc` to apply without restarting

Answer (score 18):

You could edit the .desktop File like this:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
```

...then put...

```
env LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0
```

to the Exec Field that the file looks afterwards like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
Comment=Eclipse Integrated Development Environment
Exec=env LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0 eclipse
Icon=eclipse
Name=Eclipse
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

I use the [unity-launcher-editor](https://launchpad.net/unity-launcher-editor) to easily change this via a GUI.

Comment: i think this is a very good solution to the problem as it leaves the installation of eclipse untouched and doesn't require you to write additional scripts and stuff... thx!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work here with Eclipse 2021-09 on Kubuntu 20.04. The line is `Exec=env LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0 GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus /home/geri/eclipse/jee-2021-09/eclipse/eclipse`, I closed Eclipse, started it from the `.desktop` but the floating scroll bars are still there. It works for the system itself after doing this: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/how-to-disable-overlay-scrollbars-in.html.

Answer (score 10):

`/usr/bin/eclipse` is a start script by itself. You can edit this in a text editor and add the following lines (the same as mentioned in other answers), below the line `GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=true`.

```
export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0
export LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0
```

Answer (score 5):

A more generic alternative to the above answers would be this simple script that I called "regular-scrollbars":

```
#!/bin/sh
LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0 "$1"
```

Save that someplace on your path, and then you can use the menu editor to add "regular-scrollbars" before any command you want (as long as it only has one argument - try `"$@"` if you think you'll need more than one).

This means you won't have to make a new script for any other programs you want to revert to the old scrollbars.

I really like the bashrc alias example too though, you could probably make it more generic by providing a list of programs you want to revert and having bashrc loop over them, adding the aliases.

Answer (score 1):

I have got the following working in Ubuntu 14.04 with Eclipse Mars 4.5.2, thanks to http://osdir.com/ml/ubuntu-bugs/2015-05/msg10672.html

```
$ more ~/.local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Eclipse
Comment=Eclipse Integrated Development Environment
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
Exec=env LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0 SWT_GTK3=0 /opt/eclipse/eclipse
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the specific issue of overlay scrollbars in Eclipse, I was able to get them working properly by following the instructions in [this blog post](http://hawkiesza.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/ubuntu-11-10-eclipse-and-overlay-scrollbars/) and [a related Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/a/39751/3986).

You edit the eclipse launch script.

```
sudo gedit /usr/bin/eclipse
```

And comment out an environment variable that is working around some old bugs that are supposedly now fixed.

```
#export GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=true
```

The next time I launched Eclipse, the scroll bars worked.

Comment: Don't do that! Editing files under /usr/bin/ is bad as they're solely managed by dpkg. They will be overwritten without any noticed upon the next (security) update of the package they belong to.