# Scrollbars missing in Eclipse

Tags: 11.04, unity, gtk, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to blacklist an individual application from using overlay-scrollbars?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36448/is-there-a-way-to-blacklist-an-individual-application-from-using-overlay-scrollba)

In their frantic quest for pixel real estate, Unity designers have set their greedy eyes on scrollbars and replaced the 30 years old standard vertical scrollbar with an evanescent slider (see for instance how Nautilus is behaving now !!!).

In addition, Steve Northover and the [Standard Widget Toolkit](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) folks where probably cooking there own scrollbar version on top of the GTK ones.

The end result of all this is that since my upgrading to 11.04, although I immediately switched back to '*Ubuntu Classic*', my eclipse IDE becomes virtually useless as scrolling through large files becomes a lengthy mouse-wheel Odyssey.

Did anybody notice ?

Is there a known fix to this situation ?

Comment: sorry Jorge, missed that duplicate.