# Acrobat Reader and Foxit's scrollbar not working

Tags: pdf, scrollbar

I've installed Acro Reader to view PDF files, but the vertical scrollbar isn't working. When I scroll it, it has no effect over the PDF file. However, I can navigate the files using the arrow keys or PgUp/PgDn.

So I installed Foxit reader to overcome this issue, and to my surprise, the same problem happened. I can't scroll down the files using the scrollbar.

The strangest thing is that this issue only occurs in AcroReader and Foxit. Every other application works perfectly.

Does anyone have an idea to fix this?

Comment: Don't know how to fix it, but another workaround is to use the mouse wheel (if you have one) for vertical scrolling, and hold down shift and use the mouse wheel for horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Does the tip mentioned above help you in some way? If you've already figured out an answer, please post and accept it here else if you are not interested in the question any longer, please do delete it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-scrollbar/+bug/882475) which is caused by the new overlay scrollbars. You might want to try one of these workarounds:

- Disable the overlay scrollbars ([globally, per user](https://askubuntu.com/a/34215/49450) or [per application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36448/is-there-a-way-to-blacklist-an-individual-application-from-using-overlay-scrollba))
- use another theme such as Carbon. Then the 'normal' scrollbars are shown.
- as Robin Green suggested, "use the mouse wheel (if you have one) for vertical scrolling, and hold down shift and use the mouse wheel for horizontal scrolling."