# How can I grab Unity scrollbars from the side of the screen?

Tags: overlay-scrollbars

I can grab normal scroll bars by moving my pointer far to the right. I'm usually able to do this without looking because the pointer stops at the edge, and the scrollbar is on the edge. I'm familiar with this to the point that I'm usually not aware of the act of scrolling.

In Unity, the visual indicator is on the edge, but the control is not. (This is presumably to prevent the control from covering up the indicator.) This means that I must now turn my head and look at where my pointer is so that I can properly grab the control.

Short of [removing overlay scrollbars](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34214/how-do-i-disable-overlay-scrollbars), is there a way to fix this?

"No, there is currently no way to fix this [because...]" is an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 2):

This will be available in the next Ubuntu release (11.10), and is not available in 11.04 (unless backported). Unfortunately some things end up getting "shipped" before they are polished :/.

Answer (score 1):

The updated scrollbars are in fact now available.

The new version adopts smart edge detection behavior, an orange highlight around the thumb and other fixes.

The thumb now shows in middle of the vertical bar when a window is close to the screen edge but not actually touching it - so the thumb now changes position acording to the position of the edge of the window.
The updated scrollbars are available from a PPA that will provide milestone updates for Natty users to test.

Run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ayatana-scrollbar-team/release

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I'm running the update and it works fine. (However in dual monitor setups where the edge is close to but not on the edge of the righthand screen no ajustment occurs (but then it doesn't currently either).

(from [NovaSkillasku](http://novatillasku.com/2011/05/20/ayatana-overlay-scrollbars-0-2-en-natty-narwhal/))