# scroll bar gets in the way of grabbing from a Pan column on the right hand side

Tags: unity, overlay-scrollbars

I've only seen this in Pan, it seems to do this on a quasi-regular basis:

[image]

The problem is how to "grab" the date column on the right hand side.  Unfortunately, the little up/down arrow widget gets in the way.

How do I grab the column from the right hand side to resize the column horizontally, shrink it to make the other columns available?

(Yes, it's some sort of bug, probably with Pan, that it does this sometimes, but I'm just asking about how fiddle with the window.)

This:

https://askubuntu.com/a/45087/45156

doesn't seem to do the trick.  I've tried resizing the window, of course.

Comment: See here: [Is there a way to blacklist an individual application from using overlay-scrollbars?](http://askubuntu.com/q/36448)

Answer (score 1):

There's something in `preferences.xml` which causes the header columns to be "infinitely" sized, I think.  Renaming `preferences.xml` "fixes" the problem:

```
thufir@dur:~/.pan2$ 
thufir@dur:~/.pan2$ 
thufir@dur:~/.pan2$ diff preferences.xml preferences.xml.a 
2a3,4
> <flag name='add-message-id-header-when-posting' value='false'/>
> <flag name='add-user-agent-header-when-posting' value='true'/>
3a6
> <flag name='always-run-editor' value='false'/>
6c9,10
< <flag name='clear-article-cache-on-shutdown' value='true'/>
---
> <flag name='clear-article-cache-on-shutdown' value='false'/>
> <flag name='compose-wrap-enabled' value='true'/>
16c20
< <flag name='main-window-is-maximized' value='false'/>
---
> <flag name='main-window-is-maximized' value='true'/>
31c35
< <flag name='mute-quoted-text' value='true'/>
---
> <flag name='mute-quoted-text' value='false'/>
46a51
> <flag name='spellcheck-enabled' value='true'/>
53a59
> <flag name='user-agent-extra-info' value='false'/>
55c61
< <flag name='wrap-article-body' value='false'/>
---
> <flag name='wrap-article-body' value='true'/>
58,64c64,72
< <int name='header-pane-action-column-width' value='24'/>
< <int name='header-pane-author-column-width' value='133'/>
< <int name='header-pane-date-column-width' value='120'/>
< <int name='header-pane-lines-column-width' value='60'/>
< <int name='header-pane-score-column-width' value='50'/>
< <int name='header-pane-state-column-width' value='24'/>
< <int name='header-pane-subject-column-width' value='400'/>
---
> <int name='get-latest-n-days-headers' value='7'/>
> <int name='get-latest-n-headers' value='99'/>
> <int name='header-pane-action-column-width' value='0'/>
> <int name='header-pane-author-column-width' value='1'/>
> <int name='header-pane-date-column-width' value='951'/>
> <int name='header-pane-lines-column-width' value='0'/>
> <int name='header-pane-score-column-width' value='0'/>
> <int name='header-pane-state-column-width' value='0'/>
> <int name='header-pane-subject-column-width' value='1'/>
67a76,77
> <int name='post-ui-height' value='744'/>
> <int name='post-ui-width' value='959'/>
71c81
< <string name='body-pane-font' value='Sans 16'/>
---
> <string name='body-pane-font' value='Sans 18'/>
80c90
< <string name='header-pane-columns' value='state,action,subject,score,author,lines,date'/>
---
> <string name='header-pane-columns' value='author,subject,date'/>
84c94
< <string name='last-visited-group' value=''/>
---
> <string name='last-visited-group' value='gmane.mail.mailman.user'/>
92a103,105
> <string name='save-article-mode' value='save-attachments'/>
> <string name='save-article-priority' value='age'/>
> <string name='save-subj-seperator' value='-'/>
111c124,126
< <geometry name='main-window' x='100' y='39' w='900' h='700'/>
---
> <geometry name='events-window' x='150' y='150' w='600' h='300'/>
> <geometry name='main-window' x='100' y='39' w='848' h='700'/>
> <geometry name='tasks-window' x='200' y='139' w='550' h='600'/>
thufir@dur:~/.pan2$
```