# How do I completely remove overlay scrollbars in 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, gui, mouse-scroll

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable overlay scrollbars?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34214/how-do-i-disable-overlay-scrollbars)

I'm using the "classic" GNOME desktop with 11.04, and my scrollbars are a fancy tiny line that you must hover over to get a popup control that allows you to scroll. This is just mildly annoying in GNOME apps (e.g. the file browser), but completely unusable in Java apps such as Eclipse, in which the popup never appears.

I've been told that this widget is called an "overlay scrollbar". How do I get rid of it for all applications?