# revert back to old style slidebars to get rid of the transparent slidebars

Tags: overlay-scrollbars

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable overlay scrollbars?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34214/how-do-i-disable-overlay-scrollbars)

Sorry not sure if this is the right place to post this. I'm trying to get rid of these annoying transparent slide bars i want the old style slide bars back. I run ubuntu classic desktop its not classic its been modified. Basically those of us that feel like i do needs a way to install old-style gnome2 . I think that would stop 90% of the complaining about natty. If there is a way to revert back to the old sytle slide bars please could you let me know how. I would even settle for getting gnome3 installed with no transparent slidebars.