# Overlay scrollbars in GTK apps under KDE

Tags: kde, overlay-scrollbars

I want t try overlay scrollbars in Eclipse. I am using KDE.

How do I enable overlay scrollbars in GTK apps under KDE?

Comment: I believe the scrollbars won't work with Eclipse.

Comment: i have i coworker who is using Eclipse on Ubuntu 11.04 and has overlay scrollbars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working:

[image]

The only thing i did (if i remember correctly) is to install `overlay-scrollbar` package.

Answer (score 1):

I think Eclipse is a Java application, not GTK. Only GTK apps are supported as present (as far as I am aware)

Comment: Eclipse uses SWT, and SWT on Linux uses GTK+

Answer (score 0):

I have got Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS and KDE 4.8.5. I tried doing [the following](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34214/how-do-i-disable-overlay-scrollbars):

> Add the line
>
> export LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0 to the file ~/.xprofile (create one, if
>   it doesn't exist).

Afterwards logged out and logged in.