# How to change the scroll bar style in Unity?

Tags: unity, scrollbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable overlay scrollbars?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34214/how-do-i-disable-overlay-scrollbars)

I don't feel Unity overlay scroll bar is comfortable. What should I do in order to get the old-style scroll bar. Please don't suggest me to install some theme pack or something like that.

Or is there any command or a setting to restore the old-style scroll bar?

Comment: You should provide more information in questions. The scrollbars have been very much improved in 12.04. But the link above should answer your question, so I'm voting to close this as a duplicate.