# Going back to standard scrollbars on Unity

Tags: 12.04, xfce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable overlay scrollbars?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34214/how-do-i-disable-overlay-scrollbars)

I am running xfce4 on a fairly normal 12.04 upgraded-from-11.10 install.

I really do not like the scroll bars. They are hard to find and click. How do I get normal, sane scrollbars back?

Comment: are you talking about the overlay scrollbars? http://askubuntu.com/questions/34214/how-do-i-disable-overlay-scrollbars

Answer (score 6):

Remove the newer overlay scrollbars; and replace them with older scrollbars:

```
sudo apt-get remove overlay-scrollbar liboverlay-scrollbar-0.2-0 liboverlay-scrollbar3-0.2-0
```

This is for 12.04, despite how it looks.

This is a screenshot of what the scrollbars look like after this command is run:

[image]

Ref: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/how-to-disable-overlay-scrollbars-in.html

Comment: And if I am not the only user of the system. Other users may like them.

Comment: does anyone really like them?

Answer (score -1):

This should do it for you: `sudo apt-get purge "scrollbar*"`