# What is the rationale of the tiny floatable scrolling bar in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, scrollbar

1. I wonder what the rationale of the tiny floatable scrolling bar is
   in 12.04?

   Does anyone feel any convenience and inconvenience about it compared to the original
   typical scrolling bar?

   Often with that tiny floatable bar, the arrow keys and pagedown and up keys don't work, which is most inconvenient.
2. How can I get the typical one back?

Thanks!

Comment: possible dupicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/34214/how-do-i-disable-overlay-scrollbars

Comment: I am curious what convenience can be brought from that change of scroll bar?

Comment: It is the decision of ubuntu team ,It is inconvenient for me So I removed it :)

Comment: http://design.canonical.com/2011/03/introducing-overlay-scrollbars-in-unity/

Comment: @coversnail Can you please make this an answer (including the link posted by abcd?)

Comment: @coversnail: Often with that tiny floatable bar, the arrow keys and pagedown and up keys don't work, which is most inconvenient.

Comment: @Tim if this affecting your page up/down and arrow keys you should file a bug report

Comment: I Like them, as they are there only when i need them, but the scanner program I use uses scroll bars for settings...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The design decision for introducing overlay scrollbars is described in detail in this link: http://design.canonical.com/2011/03/introducing-overlay-scrollbars-in-unity/

Essentially the decision to use them is based on the belief that having ever present scrollbars is becoming obsolete in modern set-ups, as most scrolling actions are now performed by using gestures on touchpads, scroll wheels on mice and using touch screens, rather than clicking up and down arrows or dragging a scrollbar. Removing scrollbars will provide a small increase in available screen "real estate".

If you wish to remove the overlay scrollbars this is covered in the following question: [How do I disable overlay scrollbars?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34214/how-do-i-disable-overlay-scrollbars)