# How to change strange kde scrollbars?

Tags: kde, thunderbird

From a fresh Ubuntu 12.04 install I tried multiple desktops, and settled on KDE. One problem I have with it is how scrollbars are displayed in Thunderbird:

[image]

In Gimp, Dolphin, Firefox there are completely normal scrollbars. I checked on unity and this didn't happen there.

How do I change this?

Comment: Thunderbird is a GTK application. It looks like you have the oxygen-GTK theme selected for GTK, so it's using the KDE-style scrollbars. Not sure why it doesn't affect the other apps.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the overlay scrollbar as mentioned here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/34214/how-do-i-disable-overlay-scrollbars

Comment: @somoso, AFAICT, the overlay scrollbar doesn't work for Thunderbird. Disabling it will not help resolve OP's issue.

Comment: It looks like you're using QtCurve. Try switching GTK+ theme

Comment: Go to System Settings -> Application Appearance -> Gtk Configuration -> GTK Themes. What options are selected? Post a screenshot of that dialog.

Comment: @if4124l but also in Unity, Thunderbird has problems in 12.04: the scrollbar background doesn't follow the colors defined in gtkrc file and is always dark grey. While I didn't find such problem in 12.10.

Comment: This problem goes away in 14.04.  I recommend you upgrade.  Make sure gtk2 and 3 are installed and running.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get autoremove overlay-scrollbar*
```

Comment: which will do what exactly?

Comment: @underscore_d It removes support for GTK's overlay scrollbar and forces it to use the old (and in my opinion, better) flat scrolbars.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the other apps look different because while using GTK they may be using a different version, GTK2 vs GTK3. You should search for oxygen-GTK and verify that you have a GTK3 and GTK2 version installed to cover both of the major gnome toolkits.