# Autohiding scroll bar button

Tags: 13.04, gnome, scrolling

I'm not comfortable with autohiding auto-sliding scroll bar button in some gnome based applications (like gedit). Is there any way to restore a normal scroll bar? similar to one in KDE applications (like kate) or Windows applications.

Comment: Please have a look at the first two answers here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/34214/how-do-i-disable-overlay-scrollbars. The second answer has a way to disable the overlay scrollbar globally with one command.

Answer (score 0):

According to the thread linked by roadmr, this works:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove overlay-scrollbar
```