# Mousewheel does not work in gedit

Tags: gedit, mouse-scroll, plasma

I have [uninstalled](https://askubuntu.com/a/349114/126106) `overlay-scrollbar`. But in gedit mouse-wheel does not work when scrolling.
In other gnome and kde programs mouse-wheel works well; it is disabled just in gedit. I open it in kde environment.

What's wrong with gedit?

Comment: In gedit only when mouse is on the scrollbar mousewheel works.