# The last line in geany window is obscured

Tags: geany

The last line of code in Geany is semi-obscured: an underscore `_` cannot be seen, and other codes are just harder to view. I'm using ubuntu 12.04, geany 0.21.

Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to solve the problem is to use conventional scrollbars instead of overlay scrollbars. To do so, follow the instructions in [How do I disable overlay scrollbars?](https://askubuntu.com/a/177160/25656)