# Transparent background with Cinnamon

Tags: cinnamon, gtk3

I use ubuntu 14.04 with cinnamon desktop. Everything is good, but in some applications background is transparent. How to fix it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `cinnamon --replace`. Alternatively, try finding the cinnamon applet in your panel and under troubleshoot, restart.

Comment: This not work for me , same problem

Comment: Try This thread: [Fully Transparent Panel in Mint Linux](http://www.distrogeeks.com/fully-transparent-panel-mint-linux/)

Answer (score 0):

No all gtk themes are made to be used on the same context, is possible that you need disable the overlay scrollbars. As reference:

[How do I disable overlay scrollbars?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34214/how-do-i-disable-overlay-scrollbars)