# Window scroll handles/bars aren't working for me in Ubuntu. Can they be modified?

Tags: 14.04, customization, window, scrollbar

Window scroll handles/bars are aren't working for me in Ubuntu. Can they be modified?

For one thing the handles disappear, which means I have to hold the mouse in the right place to make them reappear. I don't like that.

The second thing that is just completely incomprehensible is that if I pull them all the way up, the screen doesn't necessarily go all the way up, instead I have to go down and fetch it again! This is quite annoying...

Is is possible to customize the scroll handles so I always see them and so that they scroll up all the way?

Comment: "Retarded" in English is a synonym for "Idiot" (Français:idiot, Deutsch: Idiot, Nederlands, Vlaams: Idioot, Русский: идиот, Italiano, Magyar: idiota.)  It's not a nice word. If your native language is not included in the above, look it up on Google translate.

Comment: Except for "retarded" I think his original post clearly & cleanly expressed his feelings about the subject :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scrollbar in Ubuntu is called overlay scrollbar. If you find the need to disable it, you can refer to a previous question at [How do I disable overlay scrollbars?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34214/how-do-i-disable-overlay-scrollbars).

Comment: Thx! Exactly what I wanted to know!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Unity lately, but it should have some settings, like in XFCE and old gnome2, MATE, I know there are options to edit the settings. Should be something like Window Manager Style/Themes or Appearance Style that could change the scrollbars (and the window borders, shapes, "thickness" of the edges, icons...)

May need to add a package for more Themes or Styles, depending on your particular desktop (for example, XFCE has `xfwm4-themes`) or there might even be some others to download from the web.

---

AND, I haven't run plain old Ubuntu for a while, but I do remember they started using weird scrollbars. If that's what you're talking about, then Anthony Wong's answer could be it, settings to disable the "overlay-scrollbar", or you could remove them completely with `apt-get remove overlay-scrollbar` (I think I used to do that with regular Ubuntu, but switched to XFCE that has "regular" scrollbars.

Comment: I think they're all different, on XFCE the Settings -> Appearance -> Style tab changes the scrollbars color & look/shape (and other colors & font sizes & other hard to notice things).