# Xubuntu 14.04 overlay scrollbar

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, overlay-scrollbars, scrollbar

i have xubuntu 14.04 LTS and i wan't to ask one question.I'am tried many pages ,but nowherewas this.Please help me i wan't to make my Xubuntu look like normal ubuntu(i have old laptop and the normal ubuntu is laging) and one thing is missing ,the overlay scrollbar please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this command in your terminal to enable the overlay scrollbar:

```
gsettings reset com.canonical.desktop.interface scrollbar-mode
```

Then, if you change you mind and you want to disable it, run this:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.desktop.interface scrollbar-mode normal
```

Comment: Just relized that the question was a duplicate of this: [http://askubuntu.com/questions/34214/how-do-i-disable-overlay-scrollbars?rq=1](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34214/how-do-i-disable-overlay-scrollbars?rq=1)

Comment: Thank, but before i see you answer i tried type overlay in synaptic and after log out and log in it works bu THANKS