# Is there any way to make scroll bars scroll all the way on every drag?

Tags: unity, gui, scrollbar

In large text documents, either using Geany or GEdit, when I'm some ways down the document, if I grab the scroll bar with the mouse too close to the top of the window and drag up, it only lets me scroll up the extent of the distance to the top of the window, at which point it stops. In order to scroll to the top of the document, I have to drag from near the bottom of the window.

[image]

This is odd, because the drag bar appears where ever I hover the cursor; in other OSes this isn't a problem, IIRC, because you can only drag from where ever the always-visible drag bar is.

I've lived with this for several years now, but it strikes me that there might be a better option behaviour-wise - either continuing to scroll even after the bar reaches the top of the window, or reverting to ordinary scrollbars so at least I am directed to drag from the correct place. Any ideas?

Comment: Your using Ubuntu overlay scrollbar - I think you can grab at another place lower down to drag more, you might also be able to move the orange bit directly, If you want to remove them try [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34214/how-do-i-disable-overlay-scrollbars).

Answer (score 1):

When the scrollbar shows under your pointer, you can clic on your mouse middle button (or both buttons in case you use a touchpad) to inmediatly go to the top, botton, the middle or any part of a document you point.