# How to get rid of old overlay scrollbars in after upgrade to Ubuntu 15.10 for good?

Tags: 15.10, overlay-scrollbars

I updated to 15.10 couple of days ago, and there is still plenty of apps (Deluge, TrueCrypt, ...) showing the old overlay scrollbars with dumb thumb thing.

Can I fix this, and make those apps use the new, more elegant, scrollbars?

Comment: Related or duplicate: [This older post](http://askubuntu.com/q/34214/37165) explains many ways on how to disable and remove the overlay scrollbars.

Comment: So many options... and what is the default one in clean 15.10 installation?

Comment: As 15.10 uses Gtk overlay scrollbars, rather than Unity ones, I think this is a valid question. The last answer on the referred older post (for 15.10) doesn't work - for me - at least.

Comment: @Pitel did you find a way for 15.10? Thanks.