# Is it possible to make the scrollbars wider in 15.10?

Tags: scrollbar

I just installed Ubuntu 15.10 and I'm fairly pleased with it. Among other things, I'm pleased that the [non-scrollbar scrollbars](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34214/how-do-i-disable-overlay-scrollbars) are gone, but the new ones are still too thin for me; I would rather lose a few px of real estate from my apps and win a scrollbar that I can actually click on without sniper precision.

Is it possible to make the scrollbars a bit wider without wrecking everything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean the thin GTK3 scrollbar, it is from the theme properties. This is for Ambiance.

1. Open `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css` for editing

   ```
   gksu gedit
   ```
2. Go around line 1143 and change:

   ```
       -GtkRange-slider-width: 10;
   ```

   to

   ```
       -GtkRange-slider-width: 20;
   ```

BTW, you can always take a adventure with try & fail :)

```
grep -rn scroll /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/
```

Comment: I wasn't able to do this for the Numix theme. There is no gtk-widgets.css.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of customizing a theme, set the general properties of gtk-3.0.  I wrote out how to do it earlier this week on this one.

[How to get a bigger static scrollbar (aka normal scrollbar)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775201/how-to-get-a-bigger-static-scrollbar-aka-normal-scrollbar)

Mine is the answer that has no up votes :( Here's the gist

```
$ cat .config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
.scrollbar {
  -GtkScrollbar-has-backward-stepper: true;
  -GtkScrollbar-has-forward-stepper: true;
  -GtkRange-slider-width: 20;
  -GtkRange-stepper-size: 20;
}
```