# How do I get a bigger static scrollbar (aka normal scrollbar)?

Tags: scrollbar

I'm glad the outside overlay scrollbars are finally gone.

But the scrollbar is still a razor thin line that becomes a less razor thin scrollbar, but still thin scrollbar, when the mouse hovers.

How can I get a *normal* scrollbar? I.e., like in other OSes, like in Firefox, a scrollbar that doesn't change depending on what the mouse points to, and with a nice width.

I already tried

```
gsettings set com.canonical.desktop.interface scrollbar-mode normal
```

but no luck.

Comment: how is this still a dang issue and not fix/part of standard system settings? lordy  four years ago i rage quite ubuntu over stuff like this and went  to mintier pastures...lol

Comment: @neuronet Amen, brother

Comment: GREAT QUESTION... Athena toolkit had this working in like X11R1 in 1988.  32 years later scrollbars are far far harder to use...

Comment: Seriously 100%.  This is the same in Fedora+Cinnamon as well.  The scroll bars are way too tiny.  What in the world were people thinking not having an easy option to make them bigger.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Edit this file **/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css**

Look for this line (around line 1200): **-GtkRange-slider-width: 10;**

And change 10 to a bigger number like 20 or 30, and done :)

I also think they're too small...

See this image:

[image]

If you change the scrollbar size to 16 and you want them to stay that way, and not shrink when you don't have the mouse on it, then make the changes in the picture above.

If you use a size other than 16, just experiment with the margin sizes to get it right.

Comment: I set it to 16, and commented all the hover/drag stuff and now the scrollbars are good old static ones ... They are still disappearing after a few seconds though. Is there some animation function I didn't saw ?

Comment: Ok, so right below where you made the first change you'll see these: `margin-left: 2px;` as well as `margin-right` and `margin-top`.  Change all three of these from 2px to 7px and your scrollbars will stay wide.

Comment: I added a pic to my answer to try to make it clear what you need to change in order for the scrollbars to stay large.

Comment: Thank you so much! My grandfather was really struggling with the very small scroll bars, but I changed it to 25px and now he's scrolling like a pro!

Comment: @ErtySeidohl Glad it helped out :)

Comment: Note I changed mine to 24, and 7px was still the right size to use for the margins to make sure it stayed correct on hover. Note also be sure to restart your program (e.g., Firefox) to make sure your changes take effect. Great thing.

Comment: @neuronet Thanks for the info. This really is something that you need to test out a bit and try different sizes to see what works with your setup.

Comment: This options should be made available in `Universal Access`.

Comment: On ubuntu 18.04 this answer worked better and is simpler: https://askubuntu.com/a/908584/548938

Comment: Set my margins to recommended, but now there's extra unused space, reducing viewable screen area. Then set all to 0px; No issue, all bars static, no extra padding/margin in bar. Ubu 16.

Answer (score 32):

I think you should be cautious there.  Many of us will NOT recommend you edit the system-wide defaults for a theme, unless you really do intend to interfere with the activity of all user accounts in the system.  If you happen to make an error while doing that, then it affects all user accounts. Another point of caution is that when packages are updated, your changes will be erased.

Another shortcoming of this strategy is that it only changes the behavior of one GTK theme, but you might want to change the scrollbar size in ALL GTK-3.0 themes.

Instead, edit configuration files inside a user account. The trick is to figure out which one is the shortest distance to the desired endpoint. The GTK file you edit is part of a CSS (Cascading Style Sheets) setup, so the customization you put in your account will modify the settings.

In your user account, in the folder ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css I currently have this in a file called "gtk.css"

```
.scrollbar {
  -GtkScrollbar-has-backward-stepper: true;
  -GtkScrollbar-has-forward-stepper: true;
  -GtkRange-slider-width: 20;
  -GtkRange-stepper-size: 20;
}
```

If you play around with this a little bit, you'll find it is possible to integrate many specific changes from the theme file you were editing above.  At one time I tried very hard to fiddle lots of settings, but I'm in the "keep it simple" mode now.

If you really do want to edit a lot of settings, the right thing to do is to COPY the whole gtk-widgets.css file and put it in your ~/.config/gtk-3.0 folder.  Then go to town fiddling with settings.

In the same folder, I have a file named "settings.ini"

```
[Settings]
gtk-primary-button-warps-slider = false
```

This prevents a click in the scrollbar from moving to a certain point in the file, instead it advances just one screen.  I prefer that!

The other thing worth knowing is that changing that theme file (either as previously recommended by @Dorian or by a user account change for all GTK-3.0 based themes as I suggest) only changes programs that are based on the GTK-3.0 toolkit.  It does not change the scrollbar for all applications. It is only for the ones that read that gtk-3.0 config file.  Since you are editing a gtk-3.0 theme, apps written with QT or gtk-2.0 will not change. Hence, changing the scrollbar size of all programs is rather more difficult/tedious than you might expect.

I have changed the scrollbar width in gtk-2.0 as well. This is done in
a separate folder ~/.config/gtk-2.0. The file to create is named
gtkrc

```
style "scroll"
{
 GtkScrollbar::slider-width = 20
}
```

Note that gtk-2.0 is a differently designed setup so the syntax is different, you can't just copy the gtk-3.0 css into the gtk-2.0 folder.

I have noticed that some applications behave badly when you make the scrollbar different because the size of the "grabber" inside the slider trough is not resized correctly. I suspect the scrollbar-dragging changes in @Dorian's file would help with that. I may come back and try that. I'll let you know.

Summary: The key "old time Linux system administrator advice is" DON'T edit config files on a system-wide basis.  You are putting your system at risk, your changes won't last across revisions, and it requires root access, which is never good for cosmetic things like this. Find a way to make changes in your user account.

PS. If you really you want to fiddle around with system files (sometimes I do if I really want to insist all users have my favorite football team colors as their wallpaper and color scheme :) ), the first thing you should do is make a copy of the original file and name the original "gtk-widgets.css.orig".  Then when you edit your file, save a copy of your edit as "gtk-widgets.css.20160919", where I have the YYYYMMDD date on the end of it. This way, when the deb package is updated, you'll have a copy of your edited file. The one you edit named gtk-widgets.css will be obliterated by package installation.

Comment: What does "theme file you were editing above" refer to?  "above" doesn't mean anything here.

Answer (score 22):

Changing `-GtkRange-slider-width` has no effect on the default GTK+3 theme. Instead, you can do this:

```css
scrollbar slider {
    /* Size of the slider */
    min-width: 20px;
    min-height: 20px;
    border-radius: 22px;

    /* Padding around the slider */
    border: 5px solid transparent;
}
```

(Place the above in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`.)

Comment: where should I add it?

Comment: @kenn `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`

Comment: Works like a charm on Ubuntu 18.04.  Thanks!

Comment: 9 months later: This does work like a charm under Ubuntu 18.04 - EXCEPT that it confuses the heck out of the GNUCash application.  See https://lists.gnucash.org/pipermail/gnucash-user/2019-February/082643.html.  Making these changes destroys scrollbar functionality in GNUCash, but not other apps.  Sigh.

Comment: @SteveCohen, I looked at the gnucash link. You wrote "~/.config/gtk-3.0.gtk.css" but it should be `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`. Also, gnucash appears to be a **gtk2** application, not a gtk**3** application.

Comment: If you want to set different `min-width` and `min-height` values, define two blocks `scrollbar.vertical slider` and `scrollbar.horizontal slider` and change the values accordingly. Otherwise you'll get inconsistent horizontal and vertical scrollbars.

Comment: The best answer. To change the scrollbar in Firefox I also had to copy the gtk.css file to ~/snap/firefox/323/.config/gtk3.0

Comment: Works like a charm on Ubuntu 20.04 under Gnome. Only the apps need to be restarted to get the normal scrollbar. Also got applied to Firefox 80.0.1 (64-bit) after simply restarting it. Firefox was installed normally, not via `snap` on my PC.

Answer (score 12):

Here are the steps to restore the scrollbars which don't disappear and have permanent width, i.e. "classic" ones. Tested in GNOME Flashback session in Ubuntu 16.04 (works in Unity, too).

**Step 1.** Make a backup of `/etc/environment`. Run `sudo nano /etc/environment` and add there the next line:

```
GTK_OVERLAY_SCROLLING=0
```

This will prevent scrollbar's autohide behavior.

**Step 2.** In order to avoid tampering with the main theme file `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css` we'll borrow some code from there, alter it and put it into user profile folder. Create `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` and put the next lines into it:

```
/* Adding the buttons on the edges (if you don't need them, skip the next 4 lines)
 */

.scrollbar {
  -GtkScrollbar-has-backward-stepper: 1;
  -GtkScrollbar-has-forward-stepper: 1;
}

/* Scrollbar trough squeezes when cursor hovers over it. Disabling that
 */

.scrollbar.vertical:hover:dir(ltr),
.scrollbar.vertical.dragging:dir(ltr) {
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.scrollbar.vertical:hover:dir(rtl),
.scrollbar.vertical.dragging:dir(rtl) {
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.scrollbar.horizontal:hover,
.scrollbar.horizontal.dragging,
.scrollbar.horizontal.slider:hover,
.scrollbar.horizontal.slider.dragging {
    margin-top: 0px;
}

/* Slider widens to fill the scrollbar when cursor hovers over it. Making it permanent
 */

.scrollbar.slider.vertical:dir(ltr):not(:hover):not(.dragging) {
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.scrollbar.slider.vertical:dir(rtl):not(:hover):not(.dragging) {
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.scrollbar.slider.horizontal:not(:hover):not(.dragging) {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

**Step 3.** Create `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` and add the next lines into it:

```
[Settings]
gtk-primary-button-warps-slider = false
```

This will restore page-by-page scrolling behavior when you click the scrollbar on the either side of the slider. If this file already exists, just add the last line in the `[Settings]` section of it.

**Step 4.** Uninstall `overlay-scrollbar` and `overlay-scrollbar-gtk2` packages - you won't need them anymore.

**P.S.** If you use some applications which need superuser rights (i.e. Synaptic, Gedit etc.) then you should also place these `gtk.css` and `settings.ini` files into the root's profile folder:

```
sudo cp ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css /root/.config/gtk-3.0/
sudo cp ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini /root/.config/gtk-3.0/
```

**P.P.S.** If you find that these scrollbars are too narrow for you, make them broader. Just add the next line to your `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`:

```
.scrollbar {
  -GtkRange-slider-width: 15;
}
```

Increase the width as you see fit (the default is 10). Update `/root/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` also, if needed.

Comment: I was able to increase the width with the only item: `.scrollbar {-GtkRange-slider-width: 15; …`, without all the other options you mentioned. But this was only on a virtual machine. When I tried to do the same on a desktop, nothing worked, though I had tried all of the steps. There is, I suppose a bug in Firefox 52, because on the virtual machine, where the answer helped, the scroll bar reacted correctly for the hover event, and widened automatically. On the desktop it does not handle hovers (which is actually the reason, why I need to widen the scrollbar) and the gtk.css is ignored too

Comment: @user907860 Quite the contrary, all the steps mentioned above are intended to _ignore_ the hover event completely. They are needed to make static, permanent scrollbars which never change their width, as it was in pre-Unity era.

Comment: yes, you are correct. I meant just increase of the width, without touching the hover functionality

Comment: by the way, don't you have any idea, why this does not work in Firefox 52 on a desktop, while it does on a virtual machine? http://askubuntu.com/questions/892097/why-are-gtk-3-0-custom-settings-ignored

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Messing with dconf and themes gave very weird results - not overlay, but not normal either. This answer gives normal scrollbars. It has to be done at the GTK level. Note: Ubunutu is moving to Qt soon.

Comment: @DominicCerisano Are you sure? Ubuntu is abandoning Unity and switches to GNOME, so it should stay with GTK.

Comment: They are dropping all GTK-based windowing systems, except Gnome.
If you want an alternative, only Qt-based systems are supported.
So GTK now stands for Gnome (and only Gnome) Tool Kit.  You know, the kind of thing that killed Unity.

Answer (score 7):

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and this was the only solution that changed the scrollbar for EVERYTHING, from Firefox to LibreOffice to gnome-terminal. The solutions above worked fine for one or two applications but not for everything.

Note: this gives you REALLY big scrollbars which are good for large monitors because you can see them out of the corner of your eye without looking all the way over to the side of the screen every time you want to grab one. If you want smaller ones, change all the 70px's to a smaller number like 20px or 30px and tweak accordingly.

Put the following text into `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`:

---

```
.scrollbar,
scrollbar {
-GtkScrollbar-has-backward-stepper: 1;
-GtkScrollbar-has-forward-stepper: 1;
}

scrollbar slider {
background-color: @scrollbar_track_color;
}

.scrollbar.vertical slider,
scrollbar.vertical slider {
    min-height: 150px;
    min-width: 70px;
}

.scrollbar.horizontal.slider,
scrollbar.horizontal slider {
min-width: 40px;
min-height: 10px;
}

.scrollbar.vertical.slider:hover,
scrollbar.vertical:hover slider {
min-width: 70px;
}

.scrollbar.horizontal.slider:hover,
scrollbar.horizontal:hover slider {
    min-height: 10px;
}

.scrollbar.contents,
scrollbar contents {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    background-size: 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
}

.scrollbar.trough,
scrollbar trough {
    background-image: none;
    border: none;
}

.scrollbar:hover:backdrop,
.scrollbar.dragging:backdrop,
scrollbar:hover:backdrop,
scrollbar.dragging:backdrop {
    background-color: alpha(@backdrop_selected_bg_color, 0.5);
}


.scrollbar.vertical:hover:dir(ltr),
.scrollbar.vertical:active:dir(ltr),
scrollbar.vertical:hover:dir(ltr),
scrollbar.vertical:active:dir(ltr) {
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.scrollbar.vertical:hover:dir(rtl),
.scrollbar.vertical:active:dir(rtl),
scrollbar.vertical:hover:dir(rtl),
scrollbar.vertical:active:dir(rtl) {
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.scrollbar.horizontal:hover,
.scrollbar.horizontal:active,
scrollbar.horizontal:hover,
scrollbar.horizontal:active {
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.scrollbar.slider,
scrollbar slider {
    background-color: alpha(@backdrop_filling_bg, 0.75);
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.scrollbar.slider:hover,
.scrollbar.slider:active,
scrollbar slider:hover,
scrollbar slider:active {
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 0;
}


.scrollbar.vertical:dir(ltr):not(:hover):not(.dragging),
scrollbar.vertical:dir(ltr):not(:hover):not(.dragging) {
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.scrollbar.vertical:dir(rtl):not(:hover):not(.dragging),
scrollbar.vertical:dir(rtl):not(:hover):not(.dragging) {
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.scrollbar.horizontal:not(:hover):not(.dragging),
scrollbar.horizontal:not(:hover):not(.dragging) {
    margin-top: 0px;
}


.scrollbar.slider:hover,
scrollbar slider:hover {
    background-color: alpha(@backdrop_filling_bg, 0.6);
}

.scrollbar.slider:active,
scrollbar slider:active {
    background-color: @backdrop_filling_bg;
}

.scrollbar.slider:backdrop,
scrollbar slider:backdrop {
    background-color: alpha(@backdrop_filling_bg, 0.75);
}

.scrollbar.slider:hover:backdrop,
scrollbar slider:hover:backdrop {
    background-color: alpha(@backdrop_filling_bg, 0.6;
}

.scrollbar.slider:active:backdrop,
scrollbar slider:active:backdrop {
    background-color: @backdrop_filling_bg;
}

scrollbar {
    min-width: 70px;
    min-height: 70px;
}
```

Comment: On the latest themes, this made the slider invisible. Instead, putting only the lines that deal with size works quite wsell.
Put the following text into ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css:

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 20.04 I have merged some of above solutions in order to just get thicker scrollbar on Libre Office, and not tampering with it's color.

This is the code I've merged from above answers:

```
/* Adding the buttons on the edges (if you don't need them, skip the next 4 lines)
 */

.scrollbar {
  -GtkScrollbar-has-backward-stepper: 1;
  -GtkScrollbar-has-forward-stepper: 1;
}

/* Scrollbar trough squeezes when cursor hovers over it. Disabling that
 */

.scrollbar.vertical:hover:dir(ltr),
.scrollbar.vertical.dragging:dir(ltr) {
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.scrollbar.vertical:hover:dir(rtl),
.scrollbar.vertical.dragging:dir(rtl) {
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.scrollbar.horizontal:hover,
.scrollbar.horizontal.dragging,
.scrollbar.horizontal.slider:hover,
.scrollbar.horizontal.slider.dragging {
    margin-top: 0px;
}

/* Slider widens to fill the scrollbar when cursor hovers over it. Making it permanent
 */

.scrollbar.slider.vertical:dir(ltr):not(:hover):not(.dragging) {
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.scrollbar.slider.vertical:dir(rtl):not(:hover):not(.dragging) {
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.scrollbar.slider.horizontal:not(:hover):not(.dragging) {
    margin-top: 0px;
}


.scrollbar {
  -GtkRange-slider-width: 15;
}

.scrollbar.vertical slider,
scrollbar.vertical slider {
    min-height: 150px;
    min-width: 70px;
}

.scrollbar.horizontal.slider,
scrollbar.horizontal slider {
min-width: 40px;
min-height: 10px;
}

.scrollbar.vertical.slider:hover,
scrollbar.vertical:hover slider {
min-width: 70px;
}

.scrollbar.horizontal.slider:hover,
scrollbar.horizontal:hover slider {
    min-height: 10px;
}
```