# Why are gtk-3.0 custom settings ignored?

Tags: firefox, gtk, gtk3, scrollbar

Since Firefox was updated to version 52 on Ubuntu, I started to notice an annoying problem with too thin scroll bars:

[image: firefox-narrow-scroll-bars]

I was able to find [a would be solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775201/how-to-get-a-bigger-static-scrollbar-aka-normal-scrollbar#answer-827213) to this issue: to create a file `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` with this content

```
.scrollbar {
  -GtkRange-slider-width: 20;
}
```

Without anything else this widened the scroll bars in Firefox on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a virtual machine:

[image: firefox-wide-scroll-bars]

But when I tried to apply this on my host machine (Ubuntu 16.10) it didn't.

I've tried almost everything, what I could suspect, to figure out what is the reason:

- I encrypted the home folder on the virtual machine, in an attempt to reproduce the same issue on the virtual machine;
- I tried to move the 'gtk.css' file and others to the `/root/.config/gtk-3.0` directory;
- I created additional files `settings.ini`, `.gtkrc-2.0` etc.
- I edited the `/etc/environment` file, by adding that line `GTK_OVERLAY_SCROLLING=0`

Nothing has helped, so could anyone suggest something to this, please?
What is the reason, why these files `gtk.css`, `settings.ini` are ignored on a host machine Ubuntu 16.10 and are not on a virtual machine Ubuntu 16.04?

Also, I think, it's important to mention that the scroll bars in the "host machine" Firefox don't behave correctly at all, compared to the virtual machine ones: they don't react to a hover event, that is they don't increase their width, while the scroll bars on the "virtual machine" Firefox do.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 16.04 uses GNOME 3.18 while 16.10 uses GNOME 3.20. Possibly GNOME developers have broken something, as usual.