# How do I disable overlay scrollbars on Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: overlay-scrollbars

I really hate overlay scrollbars. Solutions like

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface ubuntu-overlay-scrollbars false
```

or

```
gsettings set com.canonical.desktop.interface scrollbar-mode normal
```

aren’t working anymore, and uninstalling `overlay-scrollbar` and `overlay-scrollbar-gtk2` (and blocking such packages in `/etc/apt/preferences` from future automatic reinstalling as dependencies) also didn’t change a thing.

How can we disable this annoying "feature" on Ubuntu 17.04? thanks!

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/871075/113421) worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04.