# Where are original Ubuntu GTK CSS settings files?

Tags: 18.04, themes, gtk

I use Ubuntu 18.04.1.  I made one change to the system files and unwisely did not save the original. The change was made to the file `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css` as per [How do I get a bigger static scrollbar (aka normal scrollbar)?](https://askubuntu.com/q/775201/).

Where might I find this original file? The installation package buries such files within archives.

Answer (score 1):

The `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css` file is from the `light-themes` package. You can download the `.deb` package by running

```
apt download light-themes
```

Then you'll be able to extract the package and find the desired file inside the archive with '*data*' in its name.