# How do I get real scrollbars back?

Tags: mate, ubuntu-mate, scrolling, scrollbar

I despise these invisible scrollbars that don't exist until you hover over them and don't show you where you are on the page:

[image: Horrible invisible scroll bars]

They are horrible to use over remote desktop.

How do I get real scrollbars?  I'm using Mate desktop in Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: See if anything in https://askubuntu.com/questions/775201/how-do-i-get-a-bigger-static-scrollbar-aka-normal-scrollbar?rq=1 helps.

Comment: @endolith What are the names of affected applications?

Comment: @N0rbert The screenshot is from FSlint which I guess uses GTK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such behavior is expected if you have installed special [overlay scrollbar packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&searchon=names&keywords=overlay-scrollbar).

Remove them with

```
sudo apt purge overlay-scrollbar overlay-scrollbar-gtk2
```

and then restart the application.

---

Below is a comparison of look-and-feel:

- with *overlay-scrollbar*s

  > [image: with <code>overlay-scrollbar</code>]
- without *overlay-scrollbar*s

  > [image: without <code>overlay-scrollbar</code>]

Comment: That worked.  You're awesome.  I didn't have to reboot, just restart the application.