# Adjust the scrollbars in evolution mail client

Tags: gnome, evolution, gtk3, scrollbar

I am using the evolution mail client to interact with my work's exchange server.  The scrollbar in the client is extremely frustrating, however, because it is small, hard to click, and changes when the mouse hovers over it.  How can I get a normal scroll bar?

I've followed the procedure [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775201/how-do-i-get-a-bigger-static-scrollbar-aka-normal-scrollbar) for GTK 3.0 apps (and this successfully worked for other apps as verified by running `gnome-terminal`), but this did not change evolution's scrollbar behavior.

Comment: Providing a little more detail will help people familiar with the program and desktop answer your question. At a minimum, please specify what version of Ubuntu and desktop you're using, and how you installed Evolution (apt repos, flatpak, snap...).

Comment: I am running debian squeeze with `evolution --version` reporting 3.22.6 installed via `apt-get install evolution`.

Comment: Debian questions are off-topic: https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic. Also debian squeeze is pretty ancient, you might do better on a modern version.