# Updated how to widen scroll bar in Ubuntu

Tags: gnome-shell, scrollbar

Where might I find recent (within last Ubuntu release) a step by step for VERY newbies on how to widen the scroll bars. I spend too much time trying to hit those mini-wide scroll bars.

Thanks to all volunteers for being here... you are much appreciated - even if no one says so enough.

Comment: What answer are you talking about?  Also, what version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: [Have you tried the fix for version 17.XX](https://askubuntu.com/a/775213/167115)? Are you using the Ambiance theme? If not, then you need to edit the file for the corresponding theme you are using e.g., Adwaita. Although things have changed since 2017, Ubuntu still uses GTK themes so the answer should be the same. Alternatively, [this answer should apply to all GTK themes](https://askubuntu.com/a/908584/167115) regardless of which theme you are using.

Comment: You will have to log out and log back in to apply the changes.

Comment: @mchid Thanks - that should work. I'm not permitted to vote it as answer but is what I was looking for. IMO: Search engines need to go back to finding, not promoting.

Comment: Does this work? https://askubuntu.com/a/908584/124466