# Howto disable 3d effects/compiz on 12.10?

Tags: compiz, 12.10, 3d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I enable llvmpipe rendering in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197771/how-do-i-enable-llvmpipe-rendering-in-unity)

What would be the best way to disable 3d effects/compiz on ubuntu 12.10 (quantal quetzal)?

I found a way to disable some effects by [switching to llvmpie-rendering](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197771/how-do-i-enable-llvmpipe-rendering-in-unity) (meant for low-spec PCs and to save battery). But it seems to be very buggy and not ready to use - so I disabled it again!

PS: I welcome any additional tip/tweak to increase the overall snappiness on old hardware :-)

Comment: This isn't exactly the same question.  For example, the Ubuntu live desktop ISO includes metacity, a lightweight window manager.  `sudo stop lightdm`, and then on a text console: `X :0 & sleep 2 && DISPLAY=:0 metacity --no-composite & DISPLAY=:0 gnome-terminal &` is an answer to this question, but not to the llvmpipe question.  (FWIW, --no-composite was actually slower than --composite on an old first-gen k8 with an 8MB Matrox video card.  Too little VRAM for the drivers to enable DRI, but also too little VRAM for any 2D accel I guess. much faster than compiz, though.  :P)

Comment: If doing more than a one-off of this setup, with metacity, at use `startx` or `xinit` to get all the usual session fluff, instead of just running the X server and a window manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu 12.04 had MyUnity integrated in the System Settings panel which allowed disabling effects and animations. It looks like MyUnity has been removed from the 12.10 repository and for those who upgraded from 12.04, MyUnity does not work in 12.10 as well.

In 12.10, compiz effects and animations can be disabled by using the CompizConfig Settings Manager application as noted down [here](http://looselytyped.blogspot.in/2012/06/enabledisable-unitycompiz-window.html).