# How can I tell if I'm using LLVMPIPE?

Tags: mesa, hardware-acceleration

This question is directly based on a comment/question that can be read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197771/how-do-i-enable-llvmpipe-rendering-in-unity/202176#comment277993_202176).

---

I have a netbook with a Radeon X1200 series (RS690M) that's using the `radeon` driver.

Unfortunately, I'm experiencing serious graphical glitches that make my system unusable. [Here is a video I took for illustrative purposes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4cehexBfwRw).

Blacklisting the `radeon` driver only results in an incredibly slow desktop which is equally unusable.

I tried doing what [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197771/how-do-i-enable-llvmpipe-rendering-in-unity/202176) question suggests to force LLVMPipe to be used (with or without the `radeon` driver blacklisted), but I experienced the exact same results.

How can I tell if LLVMPipe is being used in the first place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run `glxinfo | grep renderer` on the terminal. You should read something like `Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x301)`.

If `glxinfo` isn't installed, install it by running `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils`.

Comment: Yes, I have done this, but *what do I look for*?

Comment: I've edited my answer with the string the you should see.

Comment: Simple. I guess my laptop isn't actually running LLVMPIPE after all! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Run `glxgears -info` - there's field "GL_RENDERER" in which you might get info about software renderer.