# Compiz eating all CPU

Tags: compiz, 13.04

I'm running Raring Ringtail 13.04 on a PC Core 2 Quad 3GHz with 4GB RAM and after the latest round of updates Compiz is using 40% of processors capacity when idle. Previously it was doing fine. Running top shows compiz eating up all of the CPU. All other apps appear fine. Does anyone have any ideas or experiencing the same issue?

I am using a Video Card NVidia 9800GT 1GB RAM, using drivers NVidia.

Comment: I reinstalled NVidia driver and now Compiz is normal again, using 1% of CPU.


Thank you for your reply.

Comment: A working solution is described [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/162913/5786) - I hope it helps you as much as it helped me!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps Compiz uses LLVM instead of Nvidia drivers? See [How can I tell if I'm using LLVMPIPE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226650/how-can-i-tell-if-im-using-llvmpipe) to find out.