# Ubuntu 13.04 extremely slow on my desktop

Tags: 13.04, memory-usage

I have installed ubuntu 13.04 on my desktop computer without doing any partition, and no any dual boot operating system. My desktop hardware components are given below:

1. Hard disk 500GB
2. Ram 2GB
3. Processor Core 2 duo 2.20ghz

It is running too much slow, even web browser also hang sometimes and I faced also less memory error. when I saw Memory information using `free -m` command

```
              total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1968       1737        231          0         75        880
-/+ buffers/cache:        781       1187
Swap:         2011          0       2011
```

Even a small application consumed more memory.

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention which graphics card you are using. Unless the kernel contains proper support for it, unity might fallback on LLVMPIPE rendering, which uses the CPU instead of the GPU. This mode, in my own experience, makes the UI very slow and unresponsive.

Check what mode is running with glxinfo:

```
glxinfo | grep renderer
```

glxinfo is part of the mesa-util package:

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-util
```

Check how supported your current driver is with unity:

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

Check these previous threads:

[How can I tell if I'm using LLVMPIPE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226650/how-can-i-tell-if-im-using-llvmpipe)

[Ubuntu 13.04 runs slow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320099/ubuntu-13-04-runs-slow)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/266613/ubuntu-12-10-desktop-is-too-slow

Comment: Mesa DRI Intel(R) G41

Answer (score 0):

First at all check **top** output, or **htop** and you can find problem.

What process uses cpu most of all -->  problem in Software or Hardware (HDD).

For Firefox, Chrome -> Adblock plugin and disable unused.